# Shell scripting pass string with variable for later assignment

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on Mac OSX and using bash as my shell. I was wondering if there was any way to create a string with some marker in it, that would later be evaluated. Such as:

```
Str=$(printf '%d is %s' "5" (#some string I don't know yet) )

Later...

some string I don't know yet="something I know now"
echo Str               #produces: 5 is something I know now
```

I know this in most cases could be remedy by moving the order of where I am  placing the variables, but in this case I would like the order to be as is. Or is this not even possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use printf twice.  The fist time, escape the `%s` so that it goes into the string as-is, and the second time use it as the format string.

```
Str=$(printf '%d is %%s' 5)
New="something I know now"
printf "${Str}" "${New}"
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to coding in general, do you mean something like this? `Str=$(printf '%d is \%s' "5" )` and then later `Str=$(printf $Str "$some string I don't know yet")`. Ah thank you, your edit has shown me.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but is there also a way to pass an arithmetic operators say `**` in the string and delay it's evaluation until you get the other variables in there? Say I had Str=5, and I know I wanted to raise it to the power, but I don't know what power yet.

Comment: @NoviceC You should post a new question which demonstrates an example of what you want to delay.

Comment: @NoviceC, yes, you can do that too.  Use the same trick, but at the end use `$((${Str} ${New}))`.